# Inserting data into SQL Server returns error code 00q

Tags: sql-server, cobol, sql-insert

First of all: the biggest part of my code was working a few weeks ago. In the mean time, we've swapped from a MySQL server to a SQL server and we've changed the schema design a little.

I use Percobol, which utilizes the OpenCobol compiler as far as I've read.

```
PERFORM 2010-GEBRUIKER-INSERT
PERFORM 2020-GEBRUIKER-JOINTABLE

2010-GEBRUIKER-INSERT.
MOVE "GEBRUIKER" TO GEBR_TYPE
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Gebruikers
   VALUES ( TRIM( :LOGIN ), TRIM( :ACHTERNAAM ),
            TRIM( :EMAIL ), TRIM( :PROJECTCODE ),
            TRIM( :GEBR_TYPE ), TRIM( :VOORNAAM ),
            SHA1( TRIM( :WACHTWOORD ) ) )   
END-EXEC
.

2020-GEBRUIKER-JOINTABLE.
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO LeertrajectenGebruikersJoin
   VALUES (TRIM( :PROJECTCODE ), TRIM( :LOGIN))
END-EXEC
.
```

Whereas the database design of these tables looks like this:

[image: Schema design]

When I display the values before the `INSERT` statement in `2010`, everything is shown correctly. When I try to display them after the `INSERT`, they aren't shown.

The error thrown (which is getting caught in my logger) tells me of errorcode `00q`. I've been doing some searching but can't seem to find what it means. Even more so, as far as I've seen a code starting with `00` should indicate everything is fine.

The fields used are declared like this and populated from a CSV file:

```
01 WS-INPUT.
        05 ACHTERNAAM PIC X(25) VALUE SPACES.
        05 VOORNAAM PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
        05 EMAIL PIC X(50) VALUE SPACES.
        05 LOGIN PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
        05 WACHTWOORD PIC X(11) VALUE SPACES.
        05 GEBR_TYPE PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.
        05 PROJECTCODE PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
```

What have I overlooked that could return this error?
Also important: When I change my JDBC string or inputfile string, I get notified by my logger about a faulty connection. Therefore I'm assuming both the connection and the reading of data are working as intended.

Comment: Define a PIC -(4)9 field. Move your sql error-code to that, and print/DISPLAY that. I think you'll find the q is a negative number, which you can hopefully track in your sql documentation.

Comment: 00q is -1 in Open-Cobol Zoned decimal (and many other Ascii Cobols), have a search for error code -1. As bill said you should move it to a ---9 pic field.

Comment: Alright, I'll have a look at this later today and see where it gets me. Cheers!

Comment: You also say that WS-INPUT is a "CSV file". It may have been sourced from a CSV, but this cannot directly represent a CSV, as all the fields are fixed in length and there is no provision for a separator character between each field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, since this is what you have done, according to another question, here it is from comment to answer :-)

Define a PIC -(4)9 field. Move your sql error-code to that, and print/DISPLAY that. I think you'll find the q is a negative number, which you can hopefully track in your sql documentation.