# Inserting data into table returns error code 195

Tags: sql, sql-server, cobol, error-code

This question results from advice I received in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021936/inserting-data-into-sql-server-returns-error-code-00q) one, namely the changing of my error code definition and going from there.

My problem: when trying to insert data into a table, I receive `SQLCODE 00195` and `SQLSTATE S0001`. If I understand error codes correctly, a positive non-zero number means the query succeeded but with warnings. When I look at my database, no data has been inserted.
I've found [two](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-195.aspx) [resources](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1615) which describe this error code as

> is not a recognized built-in function name

As you'll see, the two functions used in my expression are `TRIM` and `SHA1`. If I omit both of them, the same error persists.

Using the `PIC -(4)9` definition of the SQLCODE field, as suggested in my other post, returns `-195` as result, also an error code I can't seem to find anything about.

I use SQL Server 2012 and Percobol, which utilizes the OpenCobol compiler.

Declaration of fields:

```
01 SQLCODE PIC 9(5).
01 SQLSTATE PIC X(5).

01 WS-INPUT.
        05 ACHTERNAAM PIC X(25) VALUE SPACES.
        05 VOORNAAM PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
        05 EMAIL PIC X(50) VALUE SPACES.
        05 LOGIN PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
        05 WACHTWOORD PIC X(11) VALUE SPACES.
        05 GEBR_TYPE PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.
```

SQL Query:

```
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO dbo.Gebruikers
    VALUES ( TRIM( :LOGIN ), TRIM( :ACHTERNAAM ),
             TRIM( :EMAIL ), TRIM( :PROJECTCODE ),
             TRIM( :GEBR_TYPE ), TRIM( :VOORNAAM ),
             SHA1( TRIM( :WACHTWOORD ) ) )
END-EXEC
```

Database:

[image: Table overview]

Connection string:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Groep31;user=Groep31;password=somepw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solution](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/24/sql-server-trim-function-udf-trim/): `TRIM` isn't supported in SQL Server. Using `RTRIM` fixed it.

[Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx): `SHA1` isn't supported either in SQL Server. Using `HashBytes('SHA1', RTRIM(:WACHTWOORD))` fixed this (although there are some encoding issues right now).

Comment: OK, thanks for letting us know. Accept your own answer (at least when the system lets you). You must always show your SQL Codes as signed fields, as the distinction between positive and negative is very important, as you have discovered. You have also discovered what is valid SQL under in one system is not necessarily valid in another, so careful when switching from something to somethingelse.